Unable to findOne record by ID (404 not found) while it can find ALL records of the sample data in Strapi 5

Strapi Version: 5.0.2 Community
Operating System: Windows 11 Professional Version 23H2 (OS Build 22631.4249)
Database: sqlite
Node Version: v20.17.0
NPM Version: 10.8.3
Yarn Version: 1.22.22

I newly installed the Strapi using the command below and chose to create the sample data.
yarn create strapi
I published all the articles and double-checked both find and findOne permission has been granted to the Public role on Author data.
I used Google Chrome to query the Author records.
I can get ALL the Authors records through this URL:
http://localhost:1337/api/authors
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "documentId": "j32zwfrmo0h7ed5fk51qb1is",
                "name": "David Doe",
                "email": "daviddoe@strapi.io",
                "createdAt": "2024-10-03T14:54:43.775Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-10-03T14:54:43.775Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-10-03T14:54:43.772Z",
                "locale": null
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "documentId": "d7tjdbzbakg83kgnxe7818fi",
                "name": "Sarah Baker",
                "email": "sarahbaker@strapi.io",
                "createdAt": "2024-10-03T14:54:44.657Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-10-03T14:54:44.657Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-10-03T14:54:44.652Z",
                "locale": null
            }
        ],
        "meta": {
            "pagination": {
                "page": 1,
                "pageSize": 25,
                "pageCount": 1,
                "total": 2
            }
        }
    }

However, I cannot get the any individual record from URL below and it throws 404 not found error.
http://localhost:1337/api/authors/2
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 404,
        "name": "NotFoundError",
        "message": "Not Found",
        "details": {}
    }
}

I have no customization to this Author collection type.
The controller of the Gift collection ./src/api/author/controllers/author.ts is as below:
/**
 *  author controller
 */

import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';

export default factories.createCoreController('api::author.author');

did I miss any step?

Try using the documentId prop value instead of id.
http://localhost:1337/api/authors/d7tjdbzbakg83kgnxe7818fi in your case.

    import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';
    
    export default factories.createCoreRouter('api::author.author');

Suppose the CoreRouter will generate routes for these actions:

GET /authors        (find all authors)
GET /authors/:id    (find one author)
POST /authors       (create a new author)
PUT /authors/:id    (update an author)
DELETE /authors/:id (delete an author)

However, it seems find one author is not enabled by default.

/**
 * author router.
 * .\src\api\author\routes\author.ts
 */

// Core Router
//import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';
//export default factories.createCoreRouter('api::author.author');


export default {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/authors',
      handler: 'api::author.author.find',
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/authors',
      handler: 'api::author.author.create',
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      path: '/authors/:id',
      handler: 'api::author.author.update',
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'DELETE',
      path: '/authors/:id',
      handler: 'api::author.author.delete',
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/authors/:id',
      handler: 'api::author.author.findOne',
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};

/**
 *  author controller
 *  .\src\api\author\controllers\author.ts
 */

import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';

export default factories.createCoreController('api::author.author', ({ strapi }) => ({
  // Customize the findOne method
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;

    // Ensure the ID is numeric
    const authorId = parseInt(id, 10);
    if (isNaN(authorId)) {
      return ctx.badRequest('Invalid ID format');
    }

    // Fetch the author by ID using Strapi's db query API
    const author = await strapi.db.query('api::author.author').findOne({
      where: { id: authorId },
      populate: ['books'], // Populate related data if needed
    });

    if (!author) {
      return ctx.notFound('Author not found');
    }

    //return author;
        
    // You can add more custom logic here if needed
    // sanitizeOutput - exclude private fields from the response
    // This will prevent sensitive fields, like password, from being exposed in the response 
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(author, ctx);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
}));


I use custom route and controller to solve this issue. If you have any better way to solve it, please let me know.
